# How to check django-guardian get_objects_for_user permissions via ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-guardian

I have two Django `Model`s of the form:

```py
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    pass

class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='wheels', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am using [`django-guardian`](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) to enforce object level permissions. The real application has a very large number of nested objects, and it was found that the write performance for creating all of the permission objects for every nested object was prohibitively slow. So instead, `User`s are granted permissions to the top level object (`Car` in this toy example).

On REST endpoints that access `Wheel`, the [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) permissions are checked by walking the foreign key upwards (in this case `Wheel.car`) to verify if a `User` should have access to a particular `Wheel`.

How could [`get_objects_for_user`](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user) be used to get all of the `Wheel`s for which a `User` has the appropriate permission for its parent `Car`?

Specifically trying to override [`django-rest-framework-guardian`](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework-guardian)'s [`ObjectPermissionsFilter.filter_queryset`](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework-guardian/blob/master/src/rest_framework_guardian/filters.py#L16) to support filtering objects based on the permissions of one of their `ForeignKey`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by defining this `Filter` for use with the `Wheel` `ViewSet` `filter_backends`:

```py
from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend


class CarObjectPermissionsFilter(BaseFilterBackend):
    perm_format = '%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        permission = cls.perm_format % {
            'app_label': Car._meta.app_label,
            'model_name': Car._meta.model_name,
        }
        car_ids = get_objects_for_user(user, permission, Car.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
        return queryset.filter(car__in=car_ids)
```